How to prefill react hook form with existing data
I'm creating a react hook form in Gatsby. I just wanted to prefill the fields with existing data. But I'm getting this error and cannot even debug the code.
Error: "Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {id, attributes}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead." Objective: Need to prefill the form fields with backend data.
const UpdateProfilePage = () => {
    const {
        register,
        handleSubmit,
        formState: { errors },
    } = useForm();
    const [currentTab, setCurrentTab] = useState(0);
    const [imagePreview, setImagePreview] = useState(null);
    const { token, user } = useContext(CustomContext);

    //console.log('user:', user);
    //update button function

    const [jobRole, setJobRole] = useState('');
    const [profilePicture, setProfilePicture] = useState(null);
    const [bio, setBio] = useState('');
    const [personalDescription, setPersonalDescription] = useState('');
    const [areasOfInterest, setAreasOfInterest] = useState([]);
    const [areasOfExpertise, setAreasOfExpertise] = useState([]);
    const [notification, setNotification] = useState('');

    <div>
                            <label htmlFor='personaldescription'>Personal Description</label>

                            <textarea
                                id='personaldescription'
                                placeholder='Please provide a brief description of your personal interests(i.e. hobbies)'
                                value={user?.personal_description || ''}
                                className={`form-control ${
                                    errors.description ? 'is-invalid' : ''
                                }`}
                                {...register('personaldescription', {
                                    //required: 'Description is required',
                                    maxLength: {
                                        value: 1000,
                                        message: 'Description cannot exceed 1000 characters',
                                    },
                                })}
                                onChange={(e) => setPersonalDescription(e.target.value)}
                            />
                            {errors.personaldescription && (
                                <span className='text-danger'>
                                    {errors.personaldescription.message}
                                </span>
                            )}
                        </div>
}


It would be easier to help if you share a code snippet.

You are getting that error because you are not returning the jsx. Just put ‘return’ before ‘’

The error is not specific to react-hook-form or Gatsby – your React component is just missing a return statement.
Return the JSX by using return <div>...</div> where you have <div>...</div>.
